# Cairo-dock wrong position after recent reboot on 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, cairo

I have last cairo-dock. After recent reboot cairo's position is now wrong. It's centered relatively to my screen edge. I have two monitors. On right one it's now looks like:

[image]

I tried change cairo's position settings, but with no success.

I definitely can't figure out how to reset the position of this cool, but unfortunately poor maintained thing. Could a kind soul help me?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too have a multiple monitor system and had a similar problem where the dock appears at the top of my screen (it was set for the bottom of my main screen) but is not apparently responsive to mouse hovering or clicks.  After some effort I realized my mouse can activate the dock, but not by hovering over the location where the dock appears to be, but at a location on one of my other screens!  After some experimentation I found that I can enter the Cairo dock configure menu by right clicking this other location in slightly different positions (I usually have to right click on a space between the docked apps to do this) until the  Cairo dock configure menu appears.  From there I have used the position plugin to change the dock position away from the screen edge and that has fixed the problem for me.  I am using a NVIDIA card and proprietary drivers with four screens and Compiz under Ubuntu 16.04 Unity.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't resolve the issue. If I choose '0 screen' the dock is aligned in the same manner but relatively to the edge of '0 screen' instead of '1 screen'. Cairo worked good until today...

Comment: 4xy - when I said to use the position plug-in, I should have specified the "Offset from the screen's edge" section, which contains a setting called "Distance to the screen edge", which defaults to 0 on a new installation.  When this problem happens to me, I need to change the Distance to the screens edge to a larger number and then press "Apply" in the lower right corner.  This usually clears up the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I changed the current theme in 'Configure' dialog and this resolved the issue.